# Is RAWSXP a good idea to store a blob?

Tags: r

I basically have two C functions to be used from R, one of which is making some blob and the second which needs to use it. While the user is not supposed to look inside it, I thought it would be reasonable not to do any serialization/conversion to R types and just dump it to an RAWSXP.

Are there any non-obvious disadvantages of this (i.e. except of killing user's console when printing it)?

EDIT: Ok, let's say for instance that I have an array of double/int64/(4 x int16) unions which is a result of some algorithm; I want it to be have a normal R copy semantics to behave naturally from an user's point of view (thus external pointer is rather not an option) but I'm not too eager to serialize it to R objects since it would not be straightforward and would probably end in a significant memory overhead.

Comment: ...but RAWSXP _is_ a R type. Could you provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to do?  You may be able to pass around an external pointer (EXTPTRSXP).

Comment: In retrospect, I have stored those unions as a separate vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the blob is meant to persist within a single R session then it would be more natural to create, at the C level, an external pointer, and to return that to the user. This is outlined in *Writing R Extensions*, [section 5.13](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#External-pointers-and-weak-references).

One limitation of this approach is that the external pointer does not serialize, so is not saved to disk or, e.g., returned from a parallel job. This is often appropriate when the blob is a reference to a data structure that only makes sense in the context in which it was created (e.g., a file handle) but less so if it is a static data structure. In that case storing the data as a RAWSXP can be appropriate, typically as a slot or element of an S3 or S4 class with print / show methods to hide the gory details from the user. Perhaps the downside is that the RAWSXP is allocated and managed by R, e.g., subject to garbage collection, whereas the content of an external pointer would likely be allocated more directly via `Calloc` and `Free`.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin and Josh pointed out, external pointers may be preferable.

Your approach sounds related to what e.g. the [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) does: it allocates a chunk of memory *putside of R* and controls it, thereby circumventing R's memory management and constraints.  It doesn't matter for your purposes that bigmemory uses this to pass the memory back to R as a custom data type -- the external pointer makes that possible.  Other packages using external pointers are 
[RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RODBC) for a database connection object, and my [RcppDE](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppDE) package which does what [DEoptim](http://cran.r-project.org/package=DEoptim) does but in C++ and thereby allows to user-provided *compiled functions* in for the optimization, leveraging the [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) wrapper to external pointers: the `Rcpp::XPtr` class.

And as Marting rightly says, it is all in the good manual.